# Conditionally remove middle character of string

Tags: r, regex, substr

I figured this would be an easy search, but I haven't been able to find an answer. Basically I have a column from one `dataframe` that contains characters without a zero between the first and third character (e.g. **"A1"**) but my other `dataframe` contains the same variable, but with a pointless "zero" in the middle (e.g. **"A01"**).

I would like to `rbind` them, but need these `character` class values to be the same. I think I need an `ifelse` statement because there's other variables in the column that contain a second character (not a zero though).

**Example Data**

```
# Dataframe with no zeroes between the characters in column_A
set.seed(123)
df_nozero <- data.frame(column_A = c(rep("A1",5),rep("B10",5)), 
                        column_B = sample(0:100,10),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
print(df_nozero)

   column_A column_B
1        A1       29
2        A1       78
3        A1       40
4        A1       86
5        A1       91
6       B10        4
7       B10       50
8       B10       83
9       B10       51
10      B10       42

# Dataframe with zeroes between the characters in column_A
set.seed(123)
df_zero <- data.frame(column_A =  c(rep("A01",5),rep("B10",5)),
                      column_B = sample(0:50,5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
print(df_zero)

   column_A column_B
1       A01       14
2       A01       39
3       A01       20
4       A01       42
5       A01       44
6       B10       14
7       B10       39
8       B10       20
9       B10       42
10      B10       44
```

**Desired Output**

```
   column_A column_B
1        A1       29
2        A1       78
3        A1       40
4        A1       86
5        A1       91
6       B10        4
7       B10       50
8       B10       83
9       B10       51
10      B10       42
11       A1       14
12       A1       39
13       A1       20
14       A1       42
15       A1       44
16      B10       14
17      B10       39
18      B10       20
19      B10       42
20      B10       44
```

**Failed Attempts**

```
df_corrected <- df_zero
df_corrected$column_A <- ifelse(substr(df_corrected$column_A,2,2)=="0","",df_corrected$column_A)
print(df_corrected)

   column_A column_B
1                 14
2                 39
3                 20
4                 42
5                 44
6       B10       14
7       B10       39
8       B10       20
9       B10       42
10      B10       44

df_corrected$column_A <- ifelse(substr(df_corrected$column_A,2,2)=="0",substr(df_corrected$column_A,1,3),df_corrected$column_A)
print(df_corrected)

   column_A column_B
1       A01       14
2       A01       39
3       A01       20
4       A01       42
5       A01       44
6       B10       14
7       B10       39
8       B10       20
9       B10       42
10      B10       44
```

If there was a way to only choose the first and third character in `column_A`, then I could easily replace the zero with only the first and third character.

Comment: `gsub("(?<![0-9])0+", "", df_zero$column_A, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Do you know of any introductory material for `gsub`? It's hard to understand how it works exactly...

Comment: Well `gsub` only finds the pattern and replace it with whatever you provide it with. You need to learn about `Regex` (`Regular Expression`). Honestly, I myself still search or use pattern makers websites whenever I want to come up with a new pattern that I have not used recently. It is mostly about knowing about the possibility of using `regex` and looking for it, rather than becoming an expert. p.s. but there are experts here on SO who may think differently, and if I were you, I would've listened to whatever they'd say.

Comment: You can get a pretty good overview and help from the RStudio cheatsheet on regex https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf

Comment: For what its worth, [This is great for figuring out what different regex do](https://regexr.com/)